# How to replace character in URL string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the following URL string

```
[IpAddress]/Folder/\\2014\\5\\5\\abc\\\\cde\\efg\\\\IR12345676765454554\\123456.jpg]
```

to

```
[IpAddress]/Folder/2014/5/5/abc/cde/efg/IR12345676765454554/123456.jpg]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't think all the replacements are equal here. At one place /\\ is replaced with only /, then \\ is replaced with / and again \\\\ is replaced with /. Its not clear what the actual objective is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace every sequence of `/` and `\` into a single `/`. Here's a way to do it :

```
str = str.replace(/[\/\\]+/g, '/');
```

**EDIT**

for your new question in which you don't want to replace the double `/` of `"http://"` (and I guess `"file://"`, etc), you can do this :

```
str = str.replace(/(:?)([\/\\]+)/g, function(_,d,s){ return d ? d+s : '/' });
```